# R - A column from multiple tables needs to be changed from factor to character

Tags: r

I have a vector `c("d1","d2","d3")` in which d1, d2,d3 are data tables. Each of them has a column called `ID` which is a factor variable. I need to convert all `ID` columns from factor to character in d1,d2,d3 tables.

I have already tried the following:

```
  d<-c("d1","d2","d3")
  #[1]
  invisible(lapply(d,function(x){get(x)[["ID"]]<-as.character(get(x)[["ID"]])}))
  #[2]
  invisible(lapply(d,function(x){get(x)[,list(ID)] <- as.character(get(x)[,list(ID)])}))
```

Please note that I don't want to convert other factor columns from d1,d2,d3 to character columns except ID.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Are they `data.table`s or `data.frame`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that you can try. It uses `list2env` (which many people would wisely recommend against) to replace the objects in the `.GlobalEnv`.

The approach would work with `data.frame`s and `data.table`s, though it would be better to use a different approach if you were using `data.table`s.

```
d1 <- d2 <- d3 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B"), num = 1:2)
library(data.table)
d3 <- as.data.table(d1)[, ID := factor(ID)]
d1
#   ID num
# 1  A   1
# 2  B   2
str(d1)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ ID : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
#  $ num: int  1 2
str(d3)
# 'Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ ID : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
#  $ num: int  1 2
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

list2env(lapply(mget(c("d1","d2","d3")), 
                function(x) { x[["ID"]] <- as.character(x[["ID"]]) ; x}), 
         .GlobalEnv)
str(d1)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ ID : chr  "A" "B"
#   $ num: int  1 2
str(d3)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ ID : chr  "A" "B"
#   $ num: int  1 2
#   - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

---

If you ***are*** using `data.table`, you can skip the `list2env` part:

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- d2 <- d3 <- data.table(ID = factor(c("A", "B")), num = 1:2)
str(d1)
# 'Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ ID : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 2
#  $ num: int  1 2
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

lapply(mget(c("d1","d2","d3")), function(x) x[, ID := as.character(ID)][])
str(d1)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ ID : chr  "A" "B"
#   $ num: int  1 2
#   - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```